# How to hide prices in Magento default store/website

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I'm building a Magento 2 webshop with one default-store and 36 "sub-stores". Each of those are Websites (not store views), because the prices differ per store. When a user enters the site he/she needs to go through the store-locator to find the nearest store to order the goods from.

### While on a Product overview/Category page

On the default store we:

- Want to hide prices
- Replace add-to-cart buttons in product overview and redirect to the store locator module.
- Redirect users to Store-locator when they want to see the product-details page

I'd like to do something like this:

```
if(storeViewCode=="default") {

    // Show store-locator button || redirect to Store locator
}
else {

    // Show price && add-to-cart button
}
```

Can this be done? Is it a good approach? Where do I put the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not a good approach,

To shop/hide prices you can create 2 themes extending both your main theme. Then apply the no price theme to the "default-store" and the other one to the other stores.

Then on each theme you can overide the templates to change the behaviour as you wish.

You then need to add a security to prevent users from accessing pages you don't wish on the "default-store"(such as cart) you can do this by some custom code + a configuration.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Oliver. That sounds like the "Magento way"